# Access text from UILabel that is set as AccessoryView to a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiaccessoryview

A `UITableView` uses a `UILabel` as its `Accessory View`.

By using the following code, I am able to retrieve the `UILabel` but i cant figure how to access the text alone:

```
NSLog(@"text label: %@",[[self.frequencyTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]] accessoryView]);
```

**LOG:**

```
2014-04-15 12:50:16.433 SmartWatch[2771:70b] text label: <UILabel: 0xfb81870; frame = (205 4; 60 20); text = '12:50 PM'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0xfb619d0>>
```

i want to retrieve the text alone('12:50 PM').Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
NSLog(@"text label: %@",((UILabel*)[[self.frequencyTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]] accessoryView]).text);
```

However, this is not really secure, i believe it would be better to directly access your model, when you set your accessory view you should do something like :

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.text = [someArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.accessoryView = label;
```

And if you want the text just get it directly from your array

```
NSLog(@"text label: %@",[someArray objectAtIndex:0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
NSLog(@"text label: %@",((UILabel*)[[self.frequencyTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]] accessoryView]).text);
```